# "<!" character combination in ASP.NET textbox prevents postback

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

So this is very strange, and I haven't been able to find anything about it while searching.

I have an ASP.NET webforms app, and I am using the AJAX Control Toolkit's Modal Popup extender. Inside of this popup, I have a multi line textbox and some buttons. Both are ASP control. I have found that after entering the character combination "

Here is a picture of the dialog:

[The dialog that won't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgVnP.png)

And here is the markup for it:

```
<div id="notes" style="display: none">
    <asp:UpdatePanel id="upnlNotesHeader" runat="server" class="logHeader">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblNotes" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <div class="logBody" style="height:200px">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upnlNotes" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnNotesJswo" runat="server" />
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtNotes" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" MaxLength="4000" Font-Names="Arial" Rows="12" Columns="62" style="margin: 5px 0 0 5px"></asp:TextBox>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
    <div class="logBtns">
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnSaveNotes" runat="server" Text="Save" CssClass="logBtn" OnClick="btnSaveNotes_Click" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnCancelNotes" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CssClass="logBtn" OnClick="btnCancelNotes_Click" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
</div>
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: This article suggests a few solutions to this problem: http://codingstill.com/2013/01/avoiding-the-a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected/. In these situations (for ASP.NET WebForms), I use the encode/decode method.

Comment: @ConnorsFan - That was it. Turned the Validate Request setting on the page to false and everything is working now. If you submit an answer I will mark it as the correct one. Thanks so much!

Comment: Glad that it worked! I added the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from the request validation performed by ASP.NET when submitting the page. You can turn it off at the page level like this:

```
<%@ Page ValidateRequest="false" ... %>
```

An alternative, if you want to keep the validation, is to encode the content of the fields before submitting the form to the server, and decode it in code-behind.